# Download ssh public keys from GitHub and GitLab *with the comment field*

Tags: github, gitlab, github-api

On both GitHub and GitLab, you can download a user's SSH public keys with a simple `GET` request to the URL `https://server/username.keys`, 
for example:

```
curl https://github.com/unclebob.keys
```

This gives:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEArmmGWKZ8UAO6myYW94liK4oMNBen6Sl7r0QAb6Et0y1kwCIBeBrHZhsSFQBzw0H517FeML9d+fBMSShZloMvw5x8nLQq5kbi4+8JXC4+CwW505fipjFY4ABj60BZioZn4Hndf8bwmCwXDHVtjfUeBD8b+Sjn7VNQ123rd1t5TLYDShk+2I4ldDhxbkFRqBF1gz3is4BsngdsHQp5AuuFWmiD2FRDRZDACdUyL8fUIP6O/3TAGFNKP2CG6//8+XHbQOYUaJ9RkSAJ453dx2PwDdiIXJyIJRO/q8wqWyRhA94XtJ77zP9BMyrRVnMClYcQoc9WBBlocp519l9vsp6jyQ==  
>   ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCoQ9S7V+CufAgwoehnf2TqsJ9LTsu8pUA3FgpS2mdVwcMcTs++8P5sQcXHLtDmNLpWN4k7NQgxaY1oXy5e25x/4VhXaJXWEt3luSw+Phv/PB2+aGLvqCUirsLTAD2r7ieMhd/pcVf/HlhNUQgnO1mupdbDyqZoGD/uCcJiYav8i/V7nJWJouHA8yq31XS2yqXp9m3VC7UZZHzUsVJA9Us5YqF0hKYeaGruIHR2bwoDF9ZFMss5t6/pzxMljU/ccYwvvRDdI7WX4o4+zLuZ6RWvsU6LGbbb0pQdB72tlV41fSefwFsk4JRdKbyV3Xjf25pV4IXOTcqhy+4JTB/jXxrF

Unfortunately, notice that there is no comment field at the end. 
On GitHub and GitLab the comment field is there in the system, you can view and edit in your profile to easily distinguish your multiple keys from each other.
But when accessing using this method, both GitHub and GitLab drop the comment field, for some reason.

Is there an easy way to get the public keys from these services? I'm aware of the REST APIs, but as far as I know they return JSON, which is not so convenient for example if I want to simply redirect the output of `curl` to append to an `authorized_keys` file. If I have to parse JSON, that adds more complexity to my scripts I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a security issue, where the comment content might leak some possibly sensitive data if it were returned ([since you can set any comment in there](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/50880)).

That is why the [very specification of that "get keys" feature in GitLab does include](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/145d93388042bd1eb75fc46e0fa1430d534770c5/spec/controllers/profile_keys_controller_spec.rb#L46-L59):

```rb
  it "should not render the comment of the key" do
        get :get_keys, username: user.username

        expect(response.body).not_to match(/dummy@gitlab.com/)
      end
```

Comment: @janos incidentally: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/722/6309 (I got 819, how many do you have?)

Comment: 121 out of 679 accepted = 17.82%. Compared to yours, 819 out of 7013 accepted = 11.67%

Comment: @janos Thank you Santa

Comment: I was later than I intended. But at least I'm glad I managed to do it before you capped!